# MySQL Extra Column Information

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm attempting to build a dynamic table which allows for multiple headers and columns with an id and text for display.

Is it possible to add information to the standard INFORMATION SCHEMA and then retrieve this information like usual.

At the moment I'm looking at having a table containing the data, a table containing the column heading information and another table which contains top header information therefore allowing for two headers. It means that each set of data will have 3 tables.

So which method is better?

Thanks

Comment: You might be looking at things the wrong way. Please explain better what you want to do. maybe add some examples.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking to do, but it sounds convoluted. DO NOT manually alter INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, changing the base structure of large projects is a big mistake. Especially if you are interested in keeping your work up-to-date. Any changes you make to the information_schema tables will have to be manually maintained and prevent successful updates to your MySQL install. Depending on the changes, it could even break your current install.

I have always had much better results with extending the project outside of it's base structure. Don't do anything that would break the ability to update your software.

With that said, MySQL is a great relational database and building on to it using triggers, procedures, views, etc. is quite effective.